# Warning XA4211 in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

> Warning XA4211: AndroidManifest.xml
>   //uses-sdk/@android:targetSdkVersion '15' is less than
>   $(TargetFrameworkVersion) 'v6.0'. Using API-23 for ACW compilation.
>   (XA4211)

I am trying change SDK version but cant change.

Answer (score 8):

The warning is pretty much self explanatory - you're trying to target an Android version that is lower than that of your target framework, which, naturally, is not recommended.

If you're going to change your Target Android Version (found in Android Application settings), make sure your Target Framework (found in General settings) is not higher, or you will run into compatibility issues.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting a similar error in Visual Studio 2015 / Xamarin, with the following settings:
Compile Using: Latest (Android 6.0); Minimum: API 22; Target: API 23.

In my case, the warning indicated 'Using API-24 for ACW compilation.'  I uninstalled the API-24 SDK package files and the warning went away.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution (for me) to the "Warning XA4211" in my Xamarin development environment. I needed to change the General Target Framework from "Use Latest Platform (Android 6.0 Marshmallow)" to "Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)."  It appears that even though the "Use Latest..." Target Framework option for my Application appeared to agree with my Target Android version (in the Android Manifest), it did not.

My lesson learned is that (for me), I will not select the "Use Latest..." Target Framework version (regardless of whether it appears to agree with my Target Android Version).  Instead, I will choose the specific Target Framework that agrees with my Target Android version.

Note that this change to the Target Framework also fixed warnings/errors when I moved my project from Visual Studio/Xamarin for Windows to Visual Studio/Xamarin for OSX.